# Should I mention that I was removed from the UK at age 14?

Tags: visas, uk, student-visas

I was removed at the age of 14, I was dependent and now I am making a student visa application. It asks:

> Have I ever been removed or deported or breached UK rules?

Should I say yes? Or should I say no because I was under 18 and it wouldn't count.

My removal reason was "refusal of asylum" and it was on a different name. Should I disclose everything or just say no and submit it?

Comment: Never lie to an immigration official, also not when filling out forms. It might make it harder to get the visa if you tell the truth (not sure there) but when you get it you are good. If you lie and are found out, you will never be trusted by immigration officials (and that can be in many more countries than the one you applied for.)

Comment: Answer truthfully and let them decide what is **relevant** or not. As a minor, your parents were probably the cause (not you), thus they may consider it **irrelevant**. But if you withhold that information now, it is you that will be held responsible.

Answer (score 8):

> Should I say yes? Or should I say no because I was under 18 and it wouldn't count.

You should say *yes.*  Then you should explain the details, and let the visa officer decide whether it counts or not.  In general, you're right that it doesn't count because of your age at the time, but it's your responsibility to tell the truth.  Failing to do so, if the officer discovers it, will lead to refusal for deception.

That's why, in general, if you're unsure how to answer a question, you should choose the answer that leads to disclosing more information.  The general principle applies here, too.